# How to Change the Color of Active class on click Navigation Bar bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap navigation bar and wanted to change the color on click active class! I have done try! can you check the issue!

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $('.navbar-nav li a').on("click", (function () {
        $('.navbar-nav').find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse" role = "navigation">

    <div class = "navbar-header">
        <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>index.php">Computer Online Shop</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php">Products</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php?type=top">Top Products</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php?type=new">New Products</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/shopping_cart.php">Shopping Cart</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/check_out.php"> Check Out </a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>deals.php">Deals</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>contactus.php">Contact US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Here is existing result with this change!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: add .active  class in css

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
        <li class='active'><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php">Products</a></li>
        <li ><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php?type=top">Top Products</a></li>
        <li ><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php?type=new">New Products</a></li>
        <li ><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/shopping_cart.php">Shopping Cart</a></li>
        <li ><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/check_out.php"> Check Out </a></li>
        <li ><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>deals.php">Deals</a></li>
        <li ><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>contactus.php">Contact US</a></li>
    </ul>
```

> you need to change on every page just apply "active" class on each page...which page are loaded

or other idea using jquery

```
<script>
        $('.navbar-nav li a').on("click", (function () {
            $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        });
    </script>
```

or

```
<script>
            $('.navbar-nav li').on("click", (function () {
                $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
</script>
```

Comment: check on header which page is loaded using if condition apply active class

Comment: i already given code above! it does not works. i have tried already your suggested code

Comment: check on which element click event fire on anchor tag or li

Answer (score 1):

U need to specify style for the current active class.

```
<script>
        $('.navbar-nav li a').on("click", (function () {
            $('.navbar-nav').find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
            // add this line to specify color of active class
            $(this).parent().find(".active").css("color","Your Chosen Color");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Plz check below code`

```js
        $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(){
         $('.navbar-nav').find(".active").removeClass("active");
         $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse" role = "navigation">

    <div class = "navbar-header">
        <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>index.php">Computer Online Shop</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Top Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Check Out </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

`

Comment: where you have added class of active in li , now code runs like this! http://prntscr.com/9fxwoi

Comment: i add .active class in .navbar-nav li

Comment: In jQuery i apply logic like below
(1) select  .navbar-nav li a
(2) check is in navbar-nav have any active class then remove it.
(3) after apply active class in parents of clicked a tag.

Comment: i have checked. not working, because no class active after on click webpage

Comment: Okey, may be on click your page will be changed. am are right?

Comment: on your code, only hover works!, as we did not add class active on `<li>`, so hyperlinks are active after click on any web page

Comment: In same page jQuery is work.. but after you click on any link and new page will load then our jQuery not pass the value is clicked. so you have to write PHP condition to pass the clicked value in your next load page..